# How to add a hyperlink on section numbers?

Tags: hyperref

I wanted to add a hyperlink on section numbers in my work. But Latex told me [image: errordescription]

And here are my codes

```
\vspace{1.5pc}
\hyperlink{page.1}{\subsection{ }}
\vspace{0.5pc}
```

Is there a way to add a link on a section number so that I can go back to the fist page by only clicking on it?

Thank you :)

Comment: This requires a little more to do than to wrap the section into a hyperlink setup. I am sure this has been asked here already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work, but I would strongly not recommend that. No one expects to jump to page one when clicking on the section number.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\hyperlink{page.1}{\thesection}}{1em}{}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\Blindtext
\section{More Testing}
\Blindtext
\section{Yet Another Test}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand \Blindtext and {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\hyperlink{page.1}{\thesection}}{1em}{}